# Update Apple Watch from multiple ViewControllers with information from UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an application where the user can update the same `UserDefaults` key in multiple ViewControllers. What I want to do is notify the Apple Watch everytime the information gets updated in one of the three ViewControllers and update it with the new values.

Here is how I'm doing it which I think is not the best way. As you can see I'm duplicating code in all three viewControllers.

What would the best way to update the Apple Watch from multiple ViewControllers?

#### Delegate Class

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  
    var window: UIWindow?
    var canPurchase:Bool = false
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Instantiate singleton for sharing the WCSession between viewControllers
    WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.startSession()
    }
}
```

#### View Controller 1:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController{
    func upDateUserDefaults(){
        /// Update UserDefaults...
        sendInfoToAppleWatch()
    }

    func sendInfoToAppleWatch(){      
        /// Read UserDefaults
        let message:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "messageKey")!

        /// Send message to Apple Watch with value from UserDefatults
        let session =  WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.session
        if session.isWatchAppInstalled && session.isPaired{
            WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.sendAgeToWatch(userMessage: message!)
        }
    }
}
```

#### View Controller 2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController{
    func upDateUserDefaults(){
        /// Update UserDefaults...
        sendInfoToAppleWatch()
    }

    func sendInfoToAppleWatch(){      
        /// Read UserDefaults
        let message:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "messageKey")!

        /// Send message to Apple Watch with value from UserDefatults
        let session =  WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.session
        if session.isWatchAppInstalled && session.isPaired{
            WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.sendAgeToWatch(userMessage: message!)
        }
    }
}
```

#### View Controller 3:

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController{
    func upDateUserDefaults(){
        /// Update UserDefaults...
        sendInfoToAppleWatch()
    }

    func sendInfoToAppleWatch(){      
        /// Read UserDefaults
        let message:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "messageKey")!

        /// Send message to Apple Watch with value from UserDefatults
        let session =  WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.session
        if session.isWatchAppInstalled && session.isPaired{
            WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.sendAgeToWatch(userMessage: message!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have the exact same method in 3 different classes, why don't you just put that method into a class that can access from all 3 viewcontrollers or add it to a protocol that all 3 controllers will adapt?

Comment: Enclosing the method in a class is basically what I ended up doing. I thought about protocols but at the end, I think it would be writing more code and the same code duplication. Originally I wasn't sure if there was a better way than these two options, I was thinking about KVO (which I'm not familiar with), delegation or notifications but I don't think any of these would be the right choice for what I needed. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: KVO is definitely not the way to go, since you don't really want to be notified about changes to a certain property. Whether the delegate pattern (for which you'd need to implement a protocol of course) or creating a utility class to encapsulate the shared methods yields the best results and requires the least amount of code is really situation specific, but I think in this case you made the right choice, encapsulating the method in a class is the best solution out of those mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the the good info.